# Disabled MTP, cannot access setting to enable

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, usb, mtp

I have an AOSP rom of android 5.0. I unchecked the MTP checkbox in the settings, all options turned grey, a few seconds later the activity closed and now I cannot open it again to enable MTP. I've tried restarts and unplugging cable.

The setting under storage > [menu] -> USB computer connection does nothing when I click it.

How can I reenable MTP (or any usb transfer option really)?

Comment: 1) Can you mention the content in `/data/property/persist.sys.usb.config`? 2) In my CM12, the activity is `com.android.settings/.UsbSettings` 3) If it ever happens again with some other settings, use `dumpsys activity recents` to quickly note the recent activities.

Comment: diag,serial_smd,serial_tty,rmnet_bam,mass_storage,adb

Comment: I can launch the activity that way (same activity name as you said), but it closes immediately, with or without computer connected through USB.