# How do I enable MTP on S4 with Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4, usb-connection-mode, mtp

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 5.0.1. I don't know the last time I tried accessing the phone with my computer but it worked using MTP.

Now I struggle enabling MTP. The phone prompt (asking for MTP/PTP) won't appear. I double checked it with another PC so the USB port doesn't seem to be the problem.

I followed [this little answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2n0if6/how_to_enable_usb_file_transfer_on_android/) but I don't have the three dots (aka context menu) on storage settings.

My PC is running Linux. But I don't think this is the problem as the phone prompt does not appear and the device is not even recognized (no /dev/-entry). But to be sure I additionally installed `mtpfs` and `mtp-tools` just to be sure. But it didn't help.

Oh. I'm using encrypted device with encrypted SD card. Does this disable MTP at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabled MTP, cannot access setting to enable](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/114700/96277) -- no answer as of yet.

Comment: Have you tried toggling USB debugging? (It may sound irrelevant, but there is a slight chance it will shed some light on the subject)

Comment: @Avia yes, I tried that while I tried if it works with USB debugging disabled.